# What's the geometric interpretation of the characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Regarding the term to calculate the characteristic polynomial:

$$p_A(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda\cdot I),$$

I wanted to know if the term $A-\lambda\cdot I$ has a geometric value/interpretation?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but it's something like a matrix that transforms a vector by A, but subtracts from the result a scaled copy of the original vector. There's nothing too deep going on here besides this. The reason why it enables us to compute eigenvalues is that at just the right values of lambda, transforming by A and then subtracting the scaled copies of original vectors just happens to move certain subspaces of the vectors to where they were at the beginning. A question you might be more interested in is, how do we classify behavior of matrices based on eigenvalues

Comment: The question I suggested will give you much more insight into how the characteristic polynomial might inform us intuitively about how a matrix behaves. And I think that's ultimately what you're after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting answer is provided by exterior algebra. It may not be what you expect if you're unfamiliar with the subject, but it can give you some geometric intuition if you accept that linear operators can also naturally act on *volumes* in the space they're defined.

The following equation holds for the $A-\lambda I$ operator:

$$\wedge^{n}\left(A-\lambda I\right)^{n}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-\lambda)^{n-r}(\wedge^{n}A^{r}),$$

where $\wedge^n A^r$ denotes the $r$-linear action of $A$ on $n$-volumes in the $n$-dimentional space.

What it says is that *the ($n$-linear) action of $A-\lambda I$ on top volumes is an operator-valued polynomial with coefficients all $r$-linear ways for $A$ to act on top volumes in the space, $0\le r\le n$.*

---

Let me explain quickly the main terms in this statement so that you don't need to learn exterior algebra to at least get a feeling for it.

First, in an $n$-dimensional space, an oriented "top volume" (conventionally called an $n$-vector) spanned by the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is an object denoted $v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n$, linear in each argument (so that if $v_1=u+w$, the volume $v_1\wedge v_2$ equals the sum $u\wedge v_2+w\wedge v_2$) and antisymmetric in each pair of them (so that swapping vectors inverts orientation: $u\wedge w=-w\wedge u$ - there are "left" and "right" volumes). Oriented top volumes form a one-dimensional vector space, hence all volumes are constant multiples of each other, and linear operators can be defined on them.
I hope you have at least some intuitive understanding now of what an oriented top volume is.

A linear operator on an $n$-dimensional space can be naturally extended to a new operator acting on *oriented top volumes*:

1. One way (the easiest to understand IMO) is by an $n$-linear action denoted above as $\wedge^n A^n(v_1\wedge \cdots\wedge v_n):=Av_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge Av_n.$ That is, $A$ acts on a volume by just acting on all the constituent vectors. For example, if $A=2I$, then $A$'s $n$-linear action will enlarge every volume $2^n$ times, twice in each dimension.
   On the other hand, e.g. in $\mathbb R^3$, $A=-2I$ enlarges volumes 8 times *and also flips its orientation* (which comes from the minus sign). Under such a transformation, a perfectly symmetric person with a ball in their right hand would become twice as tall, twice as wide and deep (their volume increasing 8 times) but the ball will be in their left hand after that.
2. There's actually a bunch of similar ways, called $r$-linear actions, $0\le r\le n$, for $A$ to act on top volumes, where the extension of an operator like $A=2I$, denoted $\wedge^n A^r$, will increase any given $n$-volume only $2^r$ times. You can find the precise definition if interested on wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Technical_details:_Definitions

---

So what the equation in the beginning says,
$$\wedge^{n}\left(A-\lambda I\right)^{n}=(-\lambda)^nI + (-\lambda)^{n-1}(\wedge^{n}A^{1})+\cdots+(-\lambda)(\wedge^{n}A^{n-1})+(\wedge^{n}A^{n}),$$
is that this peculiarly constructed from $A$ operator, $A-\lambda I$, acts in a very particular way on oriented top volumes: it is an operator-valued polynomial in $\lambda$, whose coefficients are all the $r$-linear actions of $A$ on top volumes.

In this sense, $A-\lambda I$ kind of **compactly encodes all the ways that the original $A$ acts on oriented top volumes**.

---

To answer your second question in your comment: if you ask why we search for preimages under $A-\lambda I$ of the zero vector, it's because that is the *definition* of an eigenvector - a vector s.t. $Av=\lambda v$, or equivalently $Av-\lambda I v=0 \Leftrightarrow (A-\lambda I)v=0$.

If you ask why we search for zeros of $\det(A-\lambda I)$, it comes from a deeper connection that *the determinant of $B$ is the number by which the top-action $\wedge^n B^n$ multiplies volumes*. Moreover, if $Bv=0$ for some vector $v\neq 0$, then the whole space is "flattened" to a lower dimension, and hence the top action zeroes out all volumes (i.e. $\wedge^n B^n$ is the zero operator on the volume space).
That is, if $(A-\lambda I)v=0$ for some $v\neq 0$, then $\wedge^n (A-\lambda I)^n$ must be the zero operator - it multiplies all volumes by zero, but from my previous point, this number (by which the top-action multiplies volumes) is also the determinant of the operator, therefore the determinant also has to vanish. (And as you know, we have some useful tools to compute determinants by hand, so the last representation of the problem is easiest to do and is used in practice, rather than working with volumes directly.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have two clarification questions: Firstly, in a 3-dimensional Vectorspace, does $A=-2I$ enlarge every volume by -8?

And secondly, using this explanation, can we explain why we solve $−$ after the 0-Vector to calculate the Eigenvectors?

Comment: I responded to both your questions with an edit to my answer as it was too long to fit in the comments section. You can see precisely what I added, in the answer edit history. Let me know if you have further questions!

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: Nice answer. Your bolded statement also provides the basis for a nice geometrical explanation for why two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if their characteristic matrices $A-xI$ and $B-xI$ have the same invariant factors / elementary divisors / Smith form.