# Is there an intuitive interpretation for the equivalence of λI-A and matrix similarity?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

For two matrices $A$ and $B$ over a field $k$, they are similar if and only if their corresponding characteristic matrices $λI−A$ and $λI−B$ are equivalent. Is there an intuitive explanation behind this phenomenon? I have some considerations:

The characteristic matrix $λI−A$ seems to apply a small perturbation to the original matrix $A$. We know that for all $λ$, the matrix $λI−A$ is invertible if and only if $\det (λI-A)$ is nonzero constant. Is there a geometric interpretation for this?

For matrices over the polynomial ring (i.e., polynomial matrices in the form
$λI−A$), if we consider them as a form of perturbation, what effects do elementary transformations on matrices over this polynomial ring impose on matrices over $k$?

I have already read the answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2824325/846766, but I am looking for a deeper understanding of the underlying reasons.

Comment: I’m confused by your claim in the second paragraph: “$\lambda I -A$ is invertible if and only if $A$ is nonsingular.” This fails to be true for all nonsingular real or complex matrices, for example, if we take $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4809121/129912) for the basis of a nice geometrical explanation using exterior algebra.