# Geometrical interpretation of matrix $A-\lambda I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know the fact, that seeking $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ is used for finding subspace of eigenvectors (or eigenspace) that correspond to $\lambda$. This means that every vector in $\ker(A -\lambda I)$ is stretched/shrinked by $\lambda$ under the transformation associated with $A$. But every vector in $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ simultaneously is squashed down to zero vector if we consider $A - \lambda I$ as linear transformation (because $A - \lambda I$ is non-invertible). So my question is: is this matrix used only for calculations or there is interesting geometrical interpretation which connects $A$ and $A-\lambda I$. Thanks.

Comment: There is the standard proof that eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ are exactly the (non-zero) vectors that make up the kernel of $A-\lambda I$. Have you read that? Have you tried to think about it geometrically? That being said, usually, I do personally find it difficult to visualize sums of linear maps in a neat way.

Comment: I thoroughly read topic about eigenvalues and eigenvectors, I know technical proof of fact that eigenvectors of A are in kernel of A - λI. But I used to learn linear algebra in a manner that every calculation must correspond to geometrical interpretation. So I try to "eyeball" geometrically why vectors of kernel of A - λI are eigenvectors of A.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4808707/129912

Comment: It seems difficult to find an interpretation simpler than $(A-\lambda I)X = 0 \iff AX = \lambda X$. So (in my opinion) any geometric interpretation would be less intuitive than that.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this yet but it at least comes very close:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g

Comment: Not everything in linear algebra has the corresponding geometric interpretation hence the name linear algebra not linear geometry (Quoted from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*). Having said that, I'm also looking for an answer for this specific one.

Comment: One geometric interpretation that you might find interesting: $(A - \lambda I)$ produces the "displacement vector" that would take you from $\lambda x$ to $Ax$, since of course $\lambda x + (A - \lambda I)x = Ax$.